# Open select box on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select, autocomplete

i tried to open a selectbox on focus but whenever i found some simular questions the answer was always: this is not possible.

Then i found the jquery-Ui Combobox, which creates a fake selectbox out of spans with a autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

My understanding of javascript is not good enough to figure out how the script opens the dialog.

Could you may tell me how i could open the box without clicking on the arrow?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="mySelect" onmouseover="showAllOptions()" onfocus="showAllOptions()">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>

<script>
function showAllOptions(){
    var options = document.getElementById('mySelect').options;
    document.getElementById("mySelect").setAttribute("size",options.length);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above code will help you out to show entire dropdown once you hover or focus on select box